# В чем смысл JWT?

Tags: алгоритм, веб-программирование, веб-сервер, jwt

Не могу понять преимущества JWT перед использованием обычной рандомной строки для аутентификации.

Мои суждения основаны на статьях из хабра, медиума, вики, jwt.io и т.п.

Как основное преимущество - это полезная нагрузка.

1. Допустим, мы в payload записали id пользователя и его роли (т.к. в большинство систем необходимо разрешать действия по роли или уровню пользователя), но тогда возникает вопрос с актуальностью данных, т.к. access токен может жить очень долго. Не такая большая проблема, когда у пользователя не хватает прав, но возникает проблема, когда наоборот, у пользователя была роль, к примеру, news-edit (возможность редактировать новость), а мы его разжаловали, в такой ситуации данный пользователь сможет творить что угодно. Получается, что мы можем хранить в полезной нагрузке только данные, которые не подвержены частой смене (к примеру, id). Но тогда нам необходимо будет обращаться к хранилищу для получения информации о пользователе.
2. Если Боб украл у Алисы access токен, то Боб может пользоваться этим токеном пока он не истечет, даже если Алиса воспользуется refresh токеном для обновления, ведь мы не храним нигде связи и заблокированные ключи ([Вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0)).
3. Если Боб украл у Алисы refresh токен, то он может пользоваться токенами бесконечно, просто обновляя их, т.к. опять, мы нигде не храним историю обновлений ([Вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0))

В чем смысл подписывать токены, если я могу генерировать две рандомные строки (допустим 256 символов, 0-9, A-z, !@#$%^&*()_+"№;%:?/\|[]{}'-= это примерно 89^256 комбинаций), один будет access токен, второй refresh токен. Логика использований та же, но у меня фиксированный размер токена, что положительно сказывается на хранилище, а так же я могу блокировать токены в необходимых ситуациях (например, заблокировать все токены пользователя при попытке использовать второй раз один и тот же refresh токен или при попытке использовать заблокированный токен). Зачем нужны эти понты с подписями? Этот тренд достался от блокчейна?

Comment: Всё дело в производительности. Если вы передаёте клиенту токен как случайную строку, то при каждом обращении вы вынуждены проверять валидность токена, искать пользователя, с которым он связан. Искать роли пользователя для ограничения доступа. Когда как в jwt содержится вся необходимая информация. Минусы вы отметили точно. Если они являются критичными для вас, то использовать jwt не целесообразно

Comment: @ArchDemon В JWT не получится хранить всю информацию о пользователе. Поэтому и так и так придется обращаться к хранилищу для получения данных пользователя. Какие есть реальные юзкейсы, когда использование jwt оправдывается?

Comment: Я вас не призываю хранить войну и мир в jwt, но почему вы решили, что необходимую информацию туда не запихнуть?

Comment: @ArchDemon Я не писал про объем, я писал про актуальность данных. И я попросил показать юзкейс, в котором данных из jwt достаточно для работы сервиса

Comment: Минусы вы правильно указали. Являются ли они для вас критичными. Если да, то jwt не для вас. В википедии указаны юзкейсы